# AngularJS angular.copy not working for bool

Tags: angularjs, copy, boolean

Can someone explain to me why I can get angular.copy to work with an object or array but if I try to use a boolean value, it does not work.

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.data.booleanVal = false;

angular.copy(true, $scope.data.booleanVal);

alert($scope.data.booleanVal);
```

Appropriate JSFiddle link.

http://jsfiddle.net/IgorMinar/ADukg/embedded/result/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The directions explicitly state:

Creates a deep copy of source, which should be an **object** or an **array**.

Reference: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy

Comment: Hey @lucuma I have the same problem, my service bool property is being shared in multiple controllers, if I do a shallow copy in different controllers, they end up with their own property reference and I can't deep copy bool with this method, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Create an object like `appState.myBool` and copy the object.